# Spring MVC and Flex integration over BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller, spring, integration, blazeds

Which is the best way to integrate existent spring-MVC-Project with flex. I'am using Spring-2.5 lib with annotations.

e.g my list controller:

```
package xxx.xxx.controller;

@Controller
public class ListController {

 @Autowired
 private ColorHome colorHome;

@RequestMapping("/admin/colors.do")
public ModelMap colorsHandler() {
    Collection<Object> colors = this.colorHome
            .findColors();
    return new ModelMap(colors);
}
```

I have also a colors.jsp which displays the colors. Now I would like to integrate flex as an UI-Layer. I only need to integrate the Spring-View with shown RequestMappings above.

Answer (score 1):

Go get BlazeDS. Install it using the WAR file.
You'll also need the flex jar from Spring.

In your web.xml file, add this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/flexContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Create a flex-servlet.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Create a flexContext.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
    ...
">
    <flex:message-broker />

    <flex:remoting-destination destination-id="flexService" ref="beanFromApplicationContext" />

</beans>
```

This should be enough to get you the remoting endpoints.

In Flex, create a remoteObject and give it a destination of "flexService" or whatever you set the destination-id on the  to.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a project for its integration with Flex,BlazeDS and Java.

This might help you. [Spring n Flex integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex)